# rhino mock an interface IA which implements interface IB with abstract class aB

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, abstract-class, rhino-mocks

I have a situation where I have in interface

```
public interface IA : IB
{
}
```

where

```
public interface IB
{
    List<string> Errors{get;}
    void AddError(string error);
}
```

with an abstract class

```
public abstract class B
{
    private List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Errors{get{return errors;}}
    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        if (!errors.Contains(error)) 
            errors.Add(error);
    }        
}
```

And I have a method on another class like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(IA obj)
    {            
        obj.AddError("some string");
    }
}
```

then I have a unit test where I would like to test that MyClass does what it is supposed to by passing in a stubbed IA:

```
public void Test()
{
    var sut = new MyClass();
    var input = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IA>();
    sut.MyMethod(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, input.Errors.Count);
}
```

but when it comes to the assertion, Errors is null as the base class B is not included in the stub for IA, is there any way to specify that I want the implementation of IB to be provided by an abtsract class without having to create a concrete class that derives from B?

I have missed some of the detail from this, but I will expand by saying that there are a set of interfaces like IA all implementing IB, and a set of classes like MyClass each taking a different interface and the detail of MyMethod depends on the interface IA that it accepts, but the interfaction with the implementation of IB is always the same.

Comment: Shouldn't you rather assert that `AddError` was called with the expected error as parameter? I don't know, how to do that with Moq, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: That is a fair point, and a good strategy in general, however one of the things I am testing is actaully part of the implementation contained in the base class B and how this interacts with the elements exposed by IA within the body of MyMethod.  The answer I have provided surfices, I was simply wondering now if it is possible to do this without explicitly creating an abstract implementation of IA.

Comment: Ah, OK. I have run into similarly awkward scenarios. Nowadays I generally try to follow [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which - among other things - makes testing for me a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create an abstract implementation of IA

```
public abstract class A : B, IA
{
    //abstract implementations of all properties and methods on IA, nothing concrete
}
```

this can then be stubbed in the unit test:

```
public void Test()
{
    var sut = new MyClass();
    var input = MockRepository.GenerateStub<A>();
    sut.MyMethod(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, input.Errors.Count);
}
```

and the propertis and methods on A that need to be stubbed (or mocked) can than be done.

It does mean that an additional class nedds to be wiritten fr each interface that exists in the vein of IA, whic is far from ideal, but its the nly way I see around this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Interface stands for behavioral contract. It is by its nature not coupled with any implementation.  What you want is a mock-ed object who carries behavior defined by class B (in other words you need a mocked B object), and at the same time implements IA.

You could use multi, partial mock to achieve it:

```
var sut = new MyClass();
var input = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<B, IA>();
sut.MyMethod((IA)input);
Assert.AreEqual(1, input.Errors.Count);
```

GeneratePartialMock is the method to mock a class who already has some behavior defined. Basically it gives you the capability to rewrite(stub) **override-able** methods defined in a class. And if you don't stub a method, the original behavior will be invoked.

You can include more interfaces (in your case, IA) in the type parameter list to dynamically add behavior to your mock-ed object.

Note you have to revise the code you posted in order to make it work:

1. Initialize () should be defined in the interface IB
2. Methods should be defined as virtual in class B

Comment: This is cleaner as it does not require a class simply for the test, however I cannot seem to get this to work. When I make the method and property on B virtual and attempt the test as written in your answer I have an **ExpectationViolationException: IB.AddError("some string"); Expected #0, Actual #1.** Adding `input.Expect(x => x.AddError("some string");` before the call to sut helps, but it also needs a `input.Expect(x => x.Errors);`.  However this then fails as `input.Errors.Count` is now 0, I am assuming that this is due to the mock having a null implementation of the `AddErrors` method.

Comment: Have you made Initialize virtual as well?

Comment: I have removed the initialize call and declaration.

Comment: doing `input.Expect(x => x.AddError("some string"));` will setup an expectation for the method, therefore no call will be made to the original method. By setting up an expectation you are telling RhinoMocks that "you know exactly what will happen", therefore the future method calls matching your expectation will be intercepted.

Comment: The same code works for me. Can you please edit your code (since it does compile at the moment anyway) and tell me what is the version of RhinoMocks you are using?

Comment: i am using rhino mocks v3.6.1

Comment: is there any chance that you forget to let B implement IB?

Comment: B does not implement IB.  What I have posted is a slimmed down example of my code. In production I have a number of classes that all implement IA (which is not blank)  I then introduced the need for some additional functionality defined in IB.  Rather than adding the implementation for this into every class, or using composition, I have derived each of these classes from B and implicity implemented IB by the fact that IA implements IB.  I have now created a cut down test which is exactly as the code in the question, with the test body being copied from yours

Comment: this looks very similar to the problem mentioned in http://ayende.com/blog/1425/a-bug-story which suggests it is a problem fixed in a old version of Rhino, yet I am having this problem with 3.6.1

Comment: Okay. Sorry didn't get your point at the first place. The problem you are having is different from what is described in ayende's blog, where the MultiClass indeed implements the IMulti interface. What you need is to **forward the IB interface to the mocked B object, since the mocked object happens to have all the required methods**. This feature is not supported by Castle DynamicProxy, which is the underlying proxy generator for RhinoMocks. Illustration can be found  here: [link](http://kozmic.net/2009/07/01/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-xi-when-one-interface-is/).

Comment: makes sense, looks like my abstract implementation of IA derived from B is going to be the only way